# Creating a project/web application of student test in which we collect inputs from "Form" and will store them in DB and will further access them & on

Tags: mysql, web-applications, webforms, session-variables, ajaxform

I am Creating a project/web application in which we collect inputs from "Form" and will store them in DB. Will access data in future for further calculation and show the result.

**So i want to know in what language i should start that project in php or java?**

**Details of project/web application:**
1. First there will be a pre form which will just create a little entry in db
2. then on the bases of that little entry new complete full test will be started
3. After completion of test from step 2 result will be stored in same data entry for further calculation
4. After calculating result will be shown to user

So how do we plan this kind of project, do we need sessions in them to change those form windows or normal jquery will do that.

Most importantly if someone can relate me with the structure of this project or if someone have same pre created any project, link, website, web application anything they can refer that will be really helpful.

I know i am sounding lame but yes i am beginner in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the approach will be using PHP where you can store data and manipulate later:

1. Make a login page will be wise because it will track which user is taking the test, you can use the session here.
2. Storing data of user once they register and provide test and store in another table.
3. For showing a result you can use both tables to show the result for every other user.

Comment: If this helps you, please mark it as correct and upvote it.